# Generic constructor for generic type in Rust

Tags: rust, struct, constructor, traits

**TL;DR: How do I guarantee I can construct arbitrary `struct`s with `WhateverStruct::new()`?**

This:

```rs
trait Constructable {
    fn new() -> Self;
}

struct Foo {
    bar: u8
    /* whatever else it may contain */
}

impl Constructable for Foo {
    fn new(baz: u8) -> Self {
        return Self { bar: baz };
    }
}
```

doesn't work, since `new()` is now not conforming to `Constructable`.

---

**Back story:**

I am trying to learn Rust by making a linked list.

In C++, Typescript, and many other languages, I can write my linked list without having to worry whether a constructor for the data type my linked list is going to store exists or not:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class LinkedListNode<T> {
    public:
        LinkedListNode(T data) { // This class doesn't care where T comes from or who constructed it or how it was constructed
            this->data = data;
        }

        T data;
};

template<typename T>
class LinkedList<T> {
    public:
        LinkedList() {
            this->head = nullptr;
        }

        /* whatever a linked list does */

        std::shared_ptr<LinkedListNode<T>> head;
};
```

In Rust, `struct`s don't seem to have the concept of a constructor by default, and so "constructor"s (`WhateverStruct::new()`) are not guaranteed to exist.

Therefore, I made myself a guarantee it will exist:

```rs
trait Constructible {
    fn new() -> Self;
}
```

So now I can do:

```rs
struct LinkedListNode<'a, T> { // a lot of convincing had to be done regarding lifetimes
    data: T,
    next: Option<&'a LinkedListNode<'a, T>> // similar to how I needed a pointer in C++ so the struct isn't infinitely recursive
}

struct LinkedList<'a, T> { // a lot of convincinng had to be done here as well
    head: Option<LinkedListNode<'a, T>>
}
```

So far so good. So now I want to test if my attempt at ensuring a "constructor" exists worked by making a new type to store in my linked list:

```rs
struct Foo {
    bar: u8
    /* whatever else it may contain */
}

impl<T> Constructable for Foo {
    fn new() -> Self {
        //
    }
}
```

I don't know what Foo might contain, but let's ignore that for now and suppose I do. I still have a problem:

```rs
impl Constructible for Foo {
    fn new(baz: u8) -> Self { // <- expected 0 params, got 1 param
        return Foo { bar: baz };
    }
}
```

Now the `new` function is no longer conforming to the `Constructable` trait.

What can I do to guarantee I can construct something?

---

A commenter wrote:

> I'm not seeing any relationship between `Constructible` and the linked list, though.

I suppose I neglected to include why I thought I needed `Constructible` because I thought the post was long already, but here it is:

```rs
impl<'a, T> Constructable for LinkedListNode<'a, T> where T: Constructable {
    fn new(/* whatever args for T here */) -> Self {
        return Self { T::new(/* whatever args for T here */), None };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let l: LinkedList::<Foo> = LinkedList::new();
    l.push(/* whatever it takes to build Foo */);
}
```

Comment: Obligatory mention / read when attempting this: [Rust with too many linked lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)

Comment: In Rust like in "C++, Typescript, and many other languages" or really any language I know of, you don't need to care whether you can construct a type to create a linked list of them either. What gave you that impression? Your C++ example doesn't ensure or make sure a specific constructor exists either. Sounds very much like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: For constructing without arguments there's [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html), and for everything else there's [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html). I'm not seeing any relationship between `Constructible` and the linked list, though.

Comment: @cafce25 Ah I think I got caught up in my own thoughts, the point I was trying to make was that one way I can design the linked list is so that I can pass data to build a new `T` when pushing into the linked list, as opposed to an already built `T`.

Comment: @drewtato The point I was trying to make is that I would like to pass data to build a new `T` instead of an already built `T`.

Comment: @cafce25 Actually, _in C++ it's not the correct way_ (at least, it is not correct to be the _only_ way). You should take the class's constructor arguments and construct it in place, to avoid the overhead of moving :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is, just like with C++, to take a parameter of type `T` in the constructor of `LinkedListNode` (be it an actual constructor or the `push()` method of the list). Also, the correct way is to not learn Rust by making a linked list - this is a bad choice; and if you feel you must, please read [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

But about the actual question you asked, this is possible, although not as nicely as with C++ and TypeScript with their variadic parameters. Make the constructor accepts a *single, generic argument*. This argument can be `()` (the unit type) to specify no additional arguments are required; it can be of any type; or it can be of *tuple* type, to specify *multiple* arguments.

```rust
trait Constructable<Arg> {
    fn new(arg: Arg) -> Self;
}

struct Foo {
    bar: u8
    /* whatever else it may contain */
}

impl Constructable<u8> for Foo {
    fn new(baz: u8) -> Self {
        return Self { bar: baz };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. As for learning by making a linked list, well, I guess my university taught linked lists as the first thing in data structures class.

Comment: @404NameNotFound Yep, that's true of all universities I know. But Rust is not a language to learn by making a data structure (it's a good thing to do, _after_ you've already mastered the language), and doubly so for this specific data structure.